# Restrict use of Microsoft Access?

Tags: windows-registry, microsoft-access, regedit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restrict use of Microsoft Access?](https://superuser.com/questions/457016/restrict-use-of-microsoft-access)

I'm trying to remove the ability for non-administrators to create databases in Microsoft Access.

My issue is that people are creating databases left and right, so I want to revoke their rights to creating databases and only let them append instead. I was thinking of doing this through RegEdit and removing the "new" option in the file tab, but I don't know how to do this, or whether it is even possible. I already know how to identify the administrators from the users, I just don't know how to edit the registry for this case.

I would be editing `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access`

Edit: Or `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`?

If anyone has any advice or experience on this, it would be a great help.

Comment: Have a little patience: [Restrict use of Microsoft Access?](http://superuser.com/questions/457016/restrict-use-of-microsoft-access)

Comment: Sorry about that, the people from Stack migrated my question from there here too.

Comment: I know, but that just means you cross-posted to both sites which is also frowned-upon. `;-)`