# Restrict creation Microsoft Access Databases per user

Tags: microsoft-access, regedit

I'm trying to remove the ability for users to create databases in Microsoft Access for **non-administrators** on a few computers.

My issue is that people are creating databases left and right, so I want to revoke those specific users rights to creating databases and only let them edit already created databases instead.

I was thinking of doing this through regedit and removing the "new" option in the file tab, but I don't know how to do this, or whether it is even possible. I already know how to identify the administrators from the users, I just don't know how to edit the registry for this case.

I would be editing

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access
EDIT: Or HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT?
```

If anyone has any advice or experience on this, it would be a great help.

Note: the [Microsoft Access Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10910) is not suitable for this as it will completely remove the ability to create databases for all users, including administrators, which I do not want to do.

Comment: Is switching the full version for the runtime for non-admins not an option for you?

Comment: It sounds like users have a need that they are filling by creating databases.  If you just switch off that ability, make *sure* that their need is filled another way to avoid resentment.

Comment: I do not understand.  Append what?

Comment: *sigh* I know how to do this in Access 2003, haven't tried it yet in Access 2010 though...In 2003 it has to do with mdw files, and mde files

Comment: Actually it wouldn't hurt if you told us what version you were using

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict use of Microsoft Access?](http://superuser.com/questions/457004/restrict-use-of-microsoft-access)

Comment: Yeah that was migrated from Stack Overflow by someone else.

Comment: Also the version is 2010.

Comment: @MRIce, I've edited your question to be slightly more specific to your requirements and consequently deleted my answer recommending the MS Access Runtime.  Your other question was migrated here because it is more suitable here, in future please do not post duplicate questions on multiple sites.